# JAX-RS POST unable to return empty xlsx as mime type

Tags: java, excel, post, jax-rs, mime-types

Here is code for my JAX-RS GET service

```
@GET
@Produces("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
@Path("/xlsReport")
public Response viewXlsReport(@QueryParam("paymentIds")String paymentIds) throws IOException
{
 List spaymentIds = Arrays.asList(paymentIds.split(","));
 XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
 XSSFSheet s1 = wb.createSheet("Some Details");
 File f = new File("Some Details.xslx");
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutStream(f);
 wb.write(fos);
 fos.close();
 return Response.ok((Object)file).build();
}
```

And POST service is like

```
@POST
@Produces("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
@Path("/exportReport")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response viewXlsReport(String ids) throws IOException
{
 List<string> sIds = new ArrayList<String>();
 StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(ids,"&");
 // populate sIds , not used in both GET & POST Version

 XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
 XSSFSheet s1 = wb.createSheet("Some Details");
 File f = new File("Some Details.xslx");
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutStream(f);
 wb.write(fos);
 fos.close();
 return Response.ok((Object)file).build();
}
```

**Issue**

- xlsx generated from GET opens fine ,
- but the one from POST gives error file format or extension is not valid

**Points to note**

1. Both code are exactly same to generate **blank** xslx file
2. Tried generating blank xlsx file from java main , same code , runs fine
3. I also checked temp files on tomcat they are ok for both GET & POST , but when i download them from IE browser i get error opening for POST file

Only difference is @GET & @POST and way paymentIds are parsed , but they are not used as we are generating blank files ( for now , will use later to hit DB and get some details )

Really Not Sure whats wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was on client side
In GET request sending correct header responseType: 'arraybuffer' , in POST i was not sending this header hence the issue